# How to install/import nb21 for plotting cumulative gain curve?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a cumulative gain curve with the library nb21. However, when trying to install it, I cannot find any pip install sources for this library. Is this library dead and are there alternative libs for this purpose?

```
from nb21 import cumulative_gain, elast

gain_curve_test_non_param = cumulative_gain(cate_test_non_param, "cate", y=y, t=T)
plt.plot(gain_curve_test_non_param, color="C0", label="Non-Parametric")
plt.plot(gain_curve_test, color="C1", label="Parametric")
plt.plot([0, 100], [0, elast(test, y, T)], linestyle="--", color="black", label="Baseline")
plt.legend();
plt.title("R-Learner");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you're referring to is from [this section](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/21-Meta-Learners.html) of the book, "Causal Inference for the Brave and True", the "nb21" module is simply the name of the Python script in their GitHub repository here https://github.com/matheusfacure/python-causality-handbook.

From their code, the `cumulative_gain()` function is minimally defined as:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from toolz import curry

@curry
def elast(data, y, t):
    return (np.sum((data[t] - data[t].mean())*(data[y] - data[y].mean())) /
            np.sum((data[t] - data[t].mean())**2))

def cumulative_gain(dataset, prediction, y, t, min_periods=30, steps=100):
    size = dataset.shape[0]
    ordered_df = dataset.sort_values(prediction, ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    n_rows = list(range(min_periods, size, size // steps)) + [size]
    return np.array([elast(ordered_df.head(rows), y, t) * (rows/size) for rows in n_rows])
```

Source: [GitHub Permalink](https://github.com/matheusfacure/python-causality-handbook/blob/f76439d66213cd263aac99b1496b8aa1c2f52362/causal-inference-for-the-brave-and-true/nb21.py)

So for your code to work, you can copy those function definitions into your file and the code should work.